# Does `config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True` reduce performance in the long run?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am interested in the costs of using `config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True`, which I read about [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1578).
I understand that there are some performance losses initially, as tensorflow allocates memory in multiple steps, but are there long run consequences?

E.g. if I have a computer that only runs tensorflow with `config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True`, will it after say an hour of training run slower (batches per second) than if I didn't use the option?

Answer (score 1):

When you use allow_growth = True , the GPU memory is not pre-allocated and will be able to grow as you need it. This will lead to smaller memory usage (as otherwise default options was to use the whole of memory) but decreases the performance if not user properly, as it requires a more complex handling of the memory.